# Angular life cycle order - clarifications?

Tags: javascript, angular

After reading the docs and many articles and examples , [**I've created a test**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hvdPGn5jCFblFlum4bdF?p=preview) plnkr:

This is a simple app that emits hooks log :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
      <h5>Lifecycle Events Log</h5>

      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let log of logs">
         <code>{{ log }}</code>
        </li>
      </ul>`
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Alice';
  logs: string[] = [];
  showChild = true;

  onLog(data) {    this.logs.push(data);  }
  ngOnInit() {      this.onLog(`onInit`);  }
  ngOnChanges() {     this.onLog(`ngOnChanges`);  }
  ngDoCheck() {    this.onLog(`doCheck`);  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {    this.onLog(`afterContentInit`);  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {   this.onLog('afterContentChecked');  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {   this.onLog(`afterViewInit`);  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {    this.onLog(`afterViewChecked`);  }
  ngOnDestroy() {   this.onLog(`onDestroy`);  }

}
```

Result:

```
Lifecycle Events Log

onInit
doCheck
afterContentInit
afterContentChecked
afterViewInit
afterViewChecked
doCheck
afterContentChecked
```

OK.

---

> `ngOnChanges` Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input
>   properties

I *don't* have here any so hence I don't see the event.

---

> `ngOnInit` - Docs : *"Called once, after the first ngOnChanges()"*.

In my example, I didn't have `ngOnChanges` and *still* `ngOnInit` emitted. So ?

---

> `ngDoCheck` Called during every change detection run. The docs also
>   says that "*immediately after ngOnChanges() and ngOnInit().*"

Why did they mention `ngOnchanges` here ?  it is called only(!) after `ngOnInit` .In my example, I don't have `ngOnChanges` and *still* `ngOnchanges` emitted. So why did they write "*`ngOnChanges()` and(!) `ngOnInit()`*" ?

---

> `ngAfterContentInit` - Docs : *"Respond after Angular projects
>   external content into the component's view."*.

This regards to transcluded components. 
But I don't have here any transclusion. So ? They say also : *"Respond after Angular **checks** the content projected into the component."* .
Checks *WHAT* ? , it is not written in the docs.

---

> `ngAfterViewChecked` -   Docs : *"Respond after Angular checks the
>   component's views and child views*"

Again - Checks What ?

---

Also - Regarding the last two events in the test -

Why do `doCheck` and `afterContentChecked` were emitted again at the end ?

Comment: `Why do doCheck and afterContentChecked were emitted again at the end ?` angular runs `Application.tick` two times on bootstrap

Comment: `Cheks` it is like check all bindings, interpolations, viewQueries, contentQueries for changes

Comment: @yurzui But that's for content meaning transclusions. I don't have here any transclusions.

Comment: @yurzui https://i.imgur.com/YdVeJKE.jpg ( I've already read that link , I even commented there ,  but I find myself reading the docs and still don't know what they means. and this makes me wonder).

Comment: It's hidden projection for Host_AppComponent

Comment: @yurzui Im sorry can you please explain this ? I don't see here any `<a><b></a>` here

Comment: To understand this better you need to debug this function https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L333-L363

Comment: I've read documentation about lifecycle hooks many times, but i also as you did't get all what there is written.

Comment: @yurzui BTW did you mean this transclusion ?https://i.imgur.com/gi37Zzz.jpg

Comment: Angular will always trigger ngOnContentInit hook if you define it in your component

Comment: @yuruzi but i can say that also for init and afterviewinit and for destroy and for docheck, No? BTW if I remove the template and uses console.log instead - - then i see different results

Comment: `then i see different results` with `afterViewChecked` at the end?

Comment: Without template result is the same

Comment: @yurzui You're right. Maybe I had a flaw in the test.

Comment: @yurzui Hi. [I found the situation where console.log is not the exact output as the UI](https://plnkr.co/edit/hvdPGn5jCFblFlum4bdF?p=preview) - [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGdJt.png)

Comment: Its the same result. Angular doesn't update view after `ngAfterViewChecked` So ngFor is not updated at the end